# Refreshing a ListBox after closing another form

Tags: .net, vb.net, forms, listbox

I have a ListBox in one form with email addresses in it. I can edit an email address by selecting it from the ListBox and pressing an "Edit" button. A new form shows up with a textbox and I can edit and save the email address. It works and edits the field in the database. (note: the 1st form doesn't disappear nor is supposed to)

Problem is: when I save the new address, the "Edit" form closes and the previous form (which remained open and visible) is showing the ListBox with the old email. I need to refresh that ListBox after editing one of its items.

Here's some code:

```
Private Sub btn_Edit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_Edit.Click

    'some irrelevant code for this

    Dim fEditCompanyEmail As New frmEditCompanyEmail(oldEmail, masterCompany, company)
    fEditCompanyEmail.Show()

End Sub
```

Above is the "Edit" button (in the form where the ListBox is)

```
Private Sub btn_Save_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_Save.Click

    Dim newEmail As String = txt_newEmail.Text

        Try

           _controller.UpdateCompanyEmail(company, newEmail, _oldEmailParameter)
           MsgBox("Email address edited successfully!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Success")
           Me.Close()

        Catch ex As Exception
           MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "#378-6 Critical Error!")
           Me.Close()
        End Try

End Sub
```

Above is the "Save" button click event handler (in the "edit email" form)

I need to refresh the ListBox on the first form as I confirm the editing of the email address in the second form.
Does anyone know how can I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: You can write a function on first form(with list view), which will refresh the list box contains. Refer to the link  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.currencymanager.refresh(v=vs.110).aspx You have to call that function using object of first form and then close the second form(edit email form).

Comment: I already have a refresh function, a public one, and am trying to access the first opened form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I got it:

I sent the first form as a parameter for the second form and passed it to a local variable "_companyForm" (changed the constructor of the second form to receive it)

```
Dim fEditCompanyEmail As New frmEditCompanyEmail(oldEmail, masterCompany, company, Me)
```

Set the refresh function to "public" in the first form.
Declared a new form and set its value to the private variable containing the first form.

```
Dim formCompany As frmCompany = _companyForm
```

And finally called the function after updating the record into the database.

```
formCompany.RefreshTabEmailList()
```

Thanks for your trouble anyway

Chiapa

Answer (score 1):

Try to invoke `RefreshItems` method after closing `fEditCompanyEmail`

```
YourProjectName.Form1.Listbox.RefreshItems()
```

Comment: That doesn't work because I haven't got an instance of the first form. I'm trying to pass the first form as a parameter to the second and will try to operate on it.

Comment: Sorry. Edited. You need to specify your project name before referencing any object

Comment: No problem, doesn't work anyway. I can access the forms shared properties but not its subs

Comment: Uhmmmmm...strange. Is your Form1 class public? `Public Class Form1`

Comment: That would explain it - but yes, it is public. I found the answer, I'm posting in it 2 mins